# How should I handle Cloudinary's cloudinary.yml in a public repo?

Tags: heroku, assets, precompile, cloudinary

I'm trying to use Heroku and Cloudinary together however slug compilation is not working because config vars are not present. Cloudinary expects an environmental variable or cloudinary.yml. I don't want to make the repo a private repo to store the cloudinary.yml file.

What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

You've likely found a good solution by now, but just in case, I'd recommend you utilizing Heroku's environment configs.

In your cloudinary.yml use environment variables:

```
production:
  cloud_name: sam-thornton
  api_key: <%= ENV["CLOUDINARY_API_KEY"] %>
  api_secret: <%= ENV["CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET"] %>
  enhance_image_tag: true
  static_image_support: true
```

And then set your Heroku config from a terminal:

```
heroku config:set CLOUDINARY_API_KEY=YOUR_KEY
heroku config:set CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET=YOUR_SECRET
```

This way you can safely keep your cloudinary.yml file in a public repository (and therefore will still be able to sync it with Heroku) without having to release sensitive information.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that appending `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false` will correct the precompilation.